# JAVA - continue after file not found exception

Tags: java, exception, bufferedreader, filereader, filenotfoundexception

I have the following function that read data from file.
If i get an IO exception, I want to finish the run of this function and continue to next functions in this program.

what should i add to the code?

I tried to add continue to the finnally block but I get error "continue cannot be used outside of a loop".

```
public void readFromFile() throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader f= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\T.DAT"));
    String l="";

    try{
        do{
            l = f.readLine();
            if(l != null)
            {
                Car a = new Car();
                a.setFromLine(l);
                alCars.add(a);
            }
        } while(line !=null);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("can't open file IO ERROR. program is continueing");
    }
    finally
    { 
        f.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply put `return;` in the finally block

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use continue outside the loop. 
Catch and finally is outside the loop.

Insert **try - catch - finally** into the **do while** clause and it would work.

If you use catch block you don't have to use throws after method signature.

Simply catch Exception in catch block, and in finally do something. 
Do first catch for IOException and in all other cases do another catch for Exception.

```
try { 
//
}
catch ( IOException e ) {
System.out.println("IO Exception occured");
}
catch ( Exception e ) {
//other exceptions
}
finally { 
//deinitialize
}
```

I am not sure if ioexception occurs, then in finally you have to close file. maybe it's null object

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything. The code will return from the function after the finally block has been executed.